# The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password

Tags: c#, iis, service-accounts

We get this error with a C# web application and deployed in multiple servers for load balancing.
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).

IIS we use service account to configure this application.

Can any one help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That CLSID belongs to Word, so you are trying to server side Office automation, which is doomed to fail, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the problem caused by insufficient account permissions. You can try to create a new user on the machine with admin privilege and assign this user on the Identity Tab of the COM service.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095688/asp-net-com-interop-excel-generation-issue-when-hosting), many users gave different methods.